# Is it possible to refresh xforms form using EMC Formula?

Tags: xforms, emc

i'm modifying data instance by adding items to itemset for combobox, but the changes are not visible after form load. I'm using EMC Formula, the refresh() and rebuild() methods called on model object don't change anything. Is there a way to apply those changes to the form?

Comment: The top hit on Google for [EMC Formula](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=EMC+Formula) is a wikipedia page for [Equilibrium moisture content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_moisture_content‎). Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Please ask the question on the [EMC Community Network](http://developer.emc.com/xmltech).